# Is fork (supposed to be) safe from signal handlers in a threaded program?

Tags: c, pthreads, deadlock, fork, signals

I'm really uncertain about the requirements POSIX places on the safety of `fork` in the presence of threads and signals. `fork` is listed as one of the async-signal-safe functions, but if there is a possibility that library code has registered `pthread_atfork` handlers which are not async-signal-safe, does this negate the safety of `fork`? Does the answer depend on whether the thread in which the signal handler is running could be in the middle of using a resource that the atfork handlers need? Or said a different way, if the atfork handlers make use of synchronization resources (mutexes, etc.) but `fork` is being called from a signal handler which executed in a thread that never accesses these resources, is the program conforming?

Building on this question, if "thread-safe" forking is implemented internally in the system library using the idioms suggested by `pthread_atfork` (obtain all locks in the prefork handler and release all locks in both the parent and child postfork handlers), then is `fork` ever safe to use from signal handlers in a threaded program? Isn't it possible that the thread handling the signal could be in the middle of a call to `malloc` or `fopen`/`fclose` and holding a global lock, resulting in deadlock during `fork`?

Finally, even if `fork` is safe in signal handlers, is it safe to `fork` in a signal handler and then return from the signal handler, or does a call to `fork` in a signal handler always necessitate a subsequent call to `_exit` or one of the `exec` family of functions before the signal handler returns?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my gut feeling says that it's a really bad idea to call `fork` from a signal handler.

Comment: @Adam: I agree wholeheartedly. I'm interested from a perspective of what guarantees the implementation must provide rather than what an application should do.

Comment: See also: [`glibc` bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trying my best to answer all the sub-questions; I apologise that some of this is vaguer than it ideally should be:

> If there is a
>   possibility that library code has
>   registered pthread_atfork handlers
>   which are not async-signal-safe, does
>   this negate the safety of fork?

Yes. The [fork documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) explicitly mentions this:

```
   When the application calls fork() from a signal handler and any of the
   fork handlers registered by pthread_atfork() calls a function that is
   not asynch-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined.
```

Of course, this means you can't actually use `pthread_atfork()` for its intended purpose of making multi-threaded libraries transparent to processes that believe they are single-threaded, because none of the pthread synchronisation functions are async-signal-safe; this is noted as a defect in the spec, see http://www.opengroup.org/austin/aardvark/latest/xshbug3.txt (search for "L16723").

> Does
>   the answer depend on whether the
>   thread in which the signal handler is
>   running could be in the middle of
>   using a resource that the atfork
>   handlers need? Or said a different
>   way, if the atfork handlers make use
>   of synchronization resources (mutexes,
>   etc.) but fork is being called from a
>   signal handler which executed in a
>   thread that never accesses these
>   resources, is the program conforming?

Strictly speaking the answer is no, because the according to the spec, functions are either async-signal-safe or they're not; there's no concept of "safe under certain circumstances". In practice you might well get away with it, but you would be vulnerable to a clunky-but-correct implementation that didn't partition its resources in the way you were expecting.

> Building on this question, if
>   "thread-safe" forking is implemented
>   internally in the system library using
>   the idioms suggested by pthread_atfork
>   (obtain all locks in the prefork
>   handler and release all locks in both
>   the parent and child postfork
>   handlers), then is fork ever safe to
>   use from signal handlers in a threaded
>   program? Isn't it possible that the
>   thread handling the signal could be in
>   the middle of a call to malloc or
>   fopen/fclose and holding a global
>   lock, resulting in deadlock during
>   fork?

If it were implemented in that way, then you're right, `fork()` from a signal handler would never be safe, because attempting to obtain a lock might deadlock if the calling thread already held it. But this implies that an implementation using such a method would not be conforming.

Looking at glibc as one example, it doesn't do that - rather, it takes two approaches: firstly, the locks that it does obtain are recursive (so if the current thread already has them, their lock count will simply be increased); further, in the child process, it simply unilaterally overwrites all the locks - see this extract from `nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fork.c`:

```
  /* Reset the file list.  These are recursive mutexes.  */
  fresetlockfiles ();

  /* Reset locks in the I/O code.  */
  _IO_list_resetlock ();

  /* Reset the lock the dynamic loader uses to protect its data.  */
  __rtld_lock_initialize (GL(dl_load_lock));
```

where each of the `resetlock` and `lock_initialize` functions ultimately call glibc's internal equivalent of `pthread_mutex_init()`, effectively resetting the mutex regardless of any waiters.

I think the theory is that, by obtaining the (recursive) lock it's guaranteed that no other threads will be touching the data structures (at least in a way that might cause a crash), and then resetting the individual locks ensures the resources aren't permanently blocked. (Resetting the current thread's lock is safe since there are now no other threads to contend for the data structure, and indeed won't be until whatever function is using the lock has returned).

I'm not 100% convinced that this covers all eventualities (not least because if/when the signal handler returns, the function that's just had its lock stolen will try to unlock it, and the internal recursive unlock function doesn't protect against unlocking too many times!) - but it seems that a workable scheme *could* be built on top of async-signal-safe recursive locks.

> Finally, even if fork is safe in
>   signal handlers, is it safe to fork in
>   a signal handler and then return from
>   the signal handler, or does a call to
>   fork in a signal handler always
>   necessitate a subsequent call to _exit
>   or one of the exec family of functions
>   before the signal handler returns?

I assume you're talking about the child process? (If `fork()` being async-signal-safe means anything then it should be possible to return in the parent!)

Not having found anything in the spec that states otherwise (though I may have missed it) I believe it *should be* safe - at least, 'safe' in the sense that returning from the signal handler in the child doesn't imply undefined behaviour in and of itself, though the fact that a multi-threaded process has just forked may imply that an `exec*()` or `_exit()` is probably the safest course of action.

Comment: Note that you can call `syscall(SYS_clone, SIGCHLD, 0)` directly instead of `fork()`. That way, you omit the atfork handlers. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810597/forkexec-without-atfork-handlers).

Comment: @Albert: This question is about what the POSIX standards guarantee. Yes, if you know you're running on Linux, and you don't care about POSIX compatibility, then you can do things like `SYS_clone` - if you think that will solve your problem - but that's not really relevant to the question :-)

Comment: Yes, agree. But maybe, once you realize that `fork` is not safe, but you actually need it, it's good to have the information how to do it in a safe way, at least on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this answer because it looks like `fork()` is likely no longer considered async-safe.  At least this seems to be the case with `glibc` but perhaps support no longer exists in POSIX.  The answer currently marked as "accepted" seems to come to the conclusion that it is safe, but at least in `glibc` that's likely not the case.

> Building on this question, if "thread-safe" forking is implemented internally in the system library using the idioms suggested by pthread_atfork (obtain all locks in the prefork handler and release all locks in both the parent and child postfork handlers), then is fork ever safe to use from signal handlers in a threaded program? Isn't it possible that the thread handling the signal could be in the middle of a call to malloc or fopen/fclose and holding a global lock, resulting in deadlock during fork?

Indeed!  It looks as if [The Open Group resolved to remove it](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_446.txt) from the list for [this very reason](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737).

IEEE 1003.1c-1995 Interpretation Request #37 regards `pthread_atfork`.

> The Interpretation Committee believes that ... the following explanatory additions be made: Pg 78 line 864 "Additionally, invocations of the fork handlers set by pthread_atfork from a fork called from a signal handler are required to be async safe."

[`glibc` Bug 4737](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4737) identifies a resolution that `fork()` be evicted from the async-safe functions list and `posix_spawn()` be used to fill its place.  Unfortunately, it was resolved as `WONTFIX` so not even the manpages were updated.

Comment: It's been almost 10 years since "The Open Group resolved to remove it", `fork()` is still very much on the [2018 list of functions required to be async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03), and [RedHat now lists this lack of POSIX conformance as a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1422161).  I'd opine that the requirement to make `fork()` async-signal-safe is not going to be removed.  After all, this is just a Linux issue as other POSIX-compliant operating systems meet the requirement.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's already removed for Issue 8, but issue 8 has not been published yet. The only way "not going to be removed" would happen in some sense is if Issue 8 is somehow never finalized/published.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE So glibc's "it's too HAAARD!" whining finally wore 'em down?  Lovely.  Nothing like lowering standards because of just ONE group.  

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, the requirement that `fork` be AS-safe and the ability to do anything useful from the child of a forked potentially-multithreaded parent are mutually exclusive. At this point POSIX has not abandoned the limitation that the child of a forked MT parent inherits an execution context that's async-signal-equivalent, but it's giving implementations the freedom to relax that requirement and provide a usable child state. When we made a change to this effect in musl, it was because at least one major interpreted language's runtime *wrongly assumes* you can do stuff in the child...

Comment: ...and **exposed that assumption as a contract with applications written in the language**. (I think it was Ruby, but I may be misremembering.) Because of this, it became not an issue just of satisfying C/POSIX programs doing bad things, but of being able to satisfy programs written in a language that were merely doing things the language documentation told them were okay to do.

Comment: Note that POSIX also has added `_Fork` which does not run atfork handlers, and which is AS-safe, so traditional single-threaded programs that need the old behavior can pretty much just `#define fork _Fork` and be happy.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Well, Ruby abuses C in a bad way - look at how it [abuses `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/cont.c#L1479) in [horrendously bug-prone ways](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5244).  `fork()` has been specified that multithreaded processes can only make async-safe calls in the child process after `fork()` [since at least SUSv2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fork.html).  And only glibc seems to have problems making `fork()` async-signal-safe because they insist on putting atfork handlers in the base libc.

Comment: I have zero sympathy for anyone demanding lowering literally decades-old standards in ways that break legacy code simply because their implementation was broken from inception.

Answer (score 2):

Using fork() in a signal handler should be fine.

pthread_atfork sounds like a bad idea to ever use.

To answer your original question, pthread cannot guarantee the safety of calling any pthread_atfork function is async-signal safe because the kernel's implementation of signals makes that impossible.

Oh, and if you fork in the signal handler, do not allow the child to return from the signal handler. That's undefined.

Comment: Do you have a citation for allowing the child to return from the signal handler being undefined?

Comment: fork() child falling off the calling function is undefined unless fflush() is called immediately before calling fork(). You cannot call fflush() from a signal handler. QED

Comment: Huh? That sounds like nonsense; the program might not even use stdio. I couldn't find any mention of `fflush` in the POSIX documentation for `fork`. And if there were such a requirement, I think it would be about falling off `main`, not the calling function...

Comment: The interaction between fork() and fflush() is well-known. I find it hard to believe it's not in the documentation.

Comment: @Joshua: You're mistaken and grossly oversimplifying things. The relevant part of the standard is 2.5.1, "Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams". The relevant requirement is: "Note that after a fork(), two handles exist where one existed before. The application shall ensure that, if both handles can ever be accessed, they are both in a state where the other could become the active handle first. The application shall prepare for a fork() exactly as if it were a change of active handle." This is completely per-`FILE` and imposes no requirements at all if `stdio` is not used.

Comment: Look, if you go way out of your way you might be able to make it defined behavior to return twice from a signal handler due to fork(), but the whole program ramifications are so great it's best not to even try.

Comment: I'm less interested in whether one *should* do this (of course the answer is "No, you shouldn't") and more interested in whether a conformant implementation must support such perverse usage.

Comment: Hmmm thread never accesses resources (e.g. while(1) sleep(1000);). It might actually be permissable if the signal handler used an anti-reentrant atomic (I don't know of a pthread based one but a programmer worth his salt might crack out the assembler to make one). Otherwise, it's fried anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from [fork source in glibc](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-2.3.91.tar.bz2%7C8nWZ2BCikBY/glibc-2.3.91/sysdeps/mach/hurd/fork.c&q=fork%20package%3aglibc) it uses signal state critical section to be sure that forking procedure will not be interrupted by a signal.

```
  ss = _hurd_self_sigstate ();
  __spin_lock (&ss->critical_section_lock);
```

And as `pthread_atfork` handlers executed after critical section lock - they become automatically signal safe.

May be I'm wrong in that, I will appreciate corrections.

Comment: I'm asking about the other way around, when `fork` is called from a signal handler. Handling a signal during `fork` is of course harmless as long as the handler does not call non-async-signal-safe functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

a fork is listed as Async-signal safe, so it can be used.

> POSIX
>
> The following table from the the Open
> Group Base Specifications [Open Group
> 2004], defines a set of functions that
> are asynchronous—signal-safe.
> Applications may invoke these
> functions, without restriction, from
> signal handler.
>
> Asynchronous—signal-safe functions
>
> **fork()**

Comment: As you can see, I've read this text already, but there are a few things I'm unclear on. In real-world implementations, is it safe? (The obvious implementation of `pthread_atfork` handlers (or equivalent) for `malloc` and `stdio` would have race conditions leading to deadlock. And second, is it permitted to return from the signal handler after forking in a signal handler, or do you need to call `_exit` or `execve` from the same signal handler?

Answer (score 0):

While implementing simple watchdog ping-ponging the main thread of my application from its child thread i've got a deadlock while calling fork() from SIG_ABRT signal handle .
[image: call stack]

Comment: While related to this question, this is not an answer. It's a new question. You should ask (post) it as a new question and cite this question as potentially relevant.