# How to call manually fork handlers registered by `pthread_atfork()`?

Tags: pthreads, fork, clone, glibc, vfork

I am using `vfork()` in glibc and according to  [`vfork()`'s man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html#:%7E:text=Fork%20handlers%20established%20using%20pthread_atfork(3)%20are%20not%20called%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%20a%20multithreaded%20program%20employing%20the%20NPTL%20threading%20library%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20calls%20vfork().%20%20Fork%20handlers%20are%20called%20in%20this%20case%20in%20a%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20program%20using%20the%20LinuxThreads%20threading%20library.):

> Fork handlers established using pthread_atfork(3) are not called
> when a multithreaded program employing the NPTL threading library
> calls vfork().  Fork handlers are called in this case in a
> program using the LinuxThreads threading library.

On NPTL fork handlers are not being called.
**In my specific case I need this protection to be engaged** so fork handlers will be called the same way as when calling `fork()`.

**Is there a way to cause pthread library to call registered handlers or even call them manually?**

I thought of using `clone()` as it gives more precise control of the cloned process but it also [avoids fork handlers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html#:%7E:text=Handlers%20registered%20using%20pthread_atfork(3)%20are%20not%20executed%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20during%20a%20clone%20call.):

> Handlers registered using pthread_atfork(3) are not executed
> during a clone call.

Also read [how to reset handlers registered by pthread_atfork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811530/how-to-reset-handlers-registered-by-pthread-atfork) - in my case I don't want to remove handlers but only call them.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your reason to call `vfork` instead of `fork`?

Comment: @EmployedRussian it's quite complex (-some method of code injection). I rely on the fact that both parent-child processes share the virtual address space.

Comment: Are you in control of the code that is registering `atfork` handlers?  Because the best solution is probably to make it stop doing that.  `atfork` handlers that actually serve the intended purpose are *extremely* hard to get right for non-trivial cases, and they aren't necessary for trivial cases.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have control over the fork handlers I register, and there are also fork handlers registered by libc which I want them to be called but I don't have direct access to.

Comment: @joepol, if libc registers any fork handlers then those should be considered an internal implementation detail, primarily of the implementation of `fork()`.  I am not aware of any such being documented.  That such handlers do not run during a `vfork()` is a matter of `vfork()` being different from `fork()`.  If the libc implementation thought it was appropriate for those behaviors to happen at a `vfork()` then it would have chosen a different means than fork handlers to implement them.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to cause pthread library to call registered handlers or even call them manually?

If you succeeded in doing this, your program would become *corrupt*. There is a *reason* `pthread_atfork` handlers aren't called on `vfork`.

---

A typical usage of `pthread_atfork` handlers is to guarantee that any locks held in the parent process are in a consistent state in both the child and the parent after the `fork`.

Without handlers, suppose thread `T1` is holding lock `L`, and thread `T2` calls `fork`. Since only `T2` will be replicated into the child, `L` will remain locked forever. If `T2` needs that lock (say it was the `malloc` lock), `T2` will deadlock (with `T1` which doesn't exist in the child).

The solution: `pthread_atfork` handlers. In the parent process `prepare()` will acquire `L`, and both `parent()` and `child()` handlers will unlock *their own instance* of `L` in the parent and child processes respectively. Everything is happy<sup>1</sup>.

---

Now consider what happens if you do the same after `vfork`. `prepare()` acquires   `L` as expected, but when you call `parent()` and `child()`, they unlock *the same instance* of `L` (because parent and child processes *share* memory). Thus `L` gets unlocked twice, corrupting it!

---

<sup>1</sup> In practice calling either `fork` or `vfork` in a multithreaded program is *fraught* with peril, and doing this safely in the presence of arbitrary libraries is near impossible.

Comment: If `pthread_atfork()` will be called with all handlers when running `vfork()` a corruption will happen as you describe, but - in the `LinuxThreads`(the GLIBC library that preceded the current - `NPTL` implementation) *fork handlers were called* and - I found a glibc function : `__run_fork_handlers()` which allows calling only part of the handlers so I can call only the parent/child handler. its in `fork.h` file but it's not in `/usr/include` so I am not sure how to use it yet..