# Is it safe to assume 8-bit char on Linux and FreeBSD, based on POSIX?

Tags: c, linux, char, posix, freebsd

POSIX mandates in Definition 3.84[1] that a byte is "exactly an octet" (8 bits). Does that make it safe to assume that a `char` is 8 bits on all Linux and FreeBSD systems (at least)?

I have some understanding of what POSIX is and what it tries to achieve, but I don't know to what extent Linux and *BSD systems "must" conform to it. For example, Linux CLI tools often do things that aren't part of their POSIX specifications (though perhaps it's always a superset, so that anything in the POSIX specification still holds true).

[1] https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_87

EDIT: I am well aware that the C standard doesn't guarantee an 8-bit byte. I'm asking specifically about whether the POSIX mandate means that "8-bit byte" is a safe assumption on **Linux and FreeBSD**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a \`char\` always-always-always have 8 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits)

Comment: It's important to note that while a `char` is usually the same as a "byte", the number of bits for a "byte" (and for `char`) doesn't have to be equal to `8`. There are platforms where the number of bits for a `char` is 16. Sure, they are not common, but the C specification doesn't limit or specify the actual number of bits for `char`. I don't know is POSIX is as open as C, considering that it grew out of Unix which was implemented for a lot of (now obscure) systems with varying word- and byte-lengths.

Comment: No, because I'm specifically asking about Linux and FreeBSD. I'm aware that the C standard doesn't specify an exact size and that in general it may be greater than 8. But thank you!

Comment: Neither Linux nor FreeBSD are claimed to be POSIX-conforming (there may be specific distributions that are claimed to be conforming or largely conforming, but not all), therefore it is not safe to assume `char` is eight bits on Linux or FreeBSD **based on POSIX**. In other words, what POSIX says is irrelevant because neither Linux nor FreeBSD is claimed to conform to what POSIX says.

Comment: If someone ports Linux or FreeBSD to some specific hardware, it is possible that a byte has more than 8 bits. You can only take assumptions if you not only specify the OS but also the underlying cpu type like x86-64 or something like that.

Comment: `Is it safe` how is "safe" defined? What does it mean when something is "safe"? I do not know how to answer - what makes "assuming 8-bit char" "safe" vs "non-safe"?

Comment: You can have 20 different run-time environments in user-space that use 20 different implementations with 20 different sizes for `char`; and all 20 different sizes for `char` can coexist (as 20 separate processes) on the same computer at the same time. The default C & C++ toolchain (and default standard libs, etc) that's shipped with the OS will try (and almost succeed) to implement a newer version of POSIX; so 8-bit `char` is the mostly likely default in practice (unless the process is Java or anything else where POSIX is completely irrelevant, where UTF-16 may be the "required standard" ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html :

```
{CHAR_BIT}
    Number of bits in a type char.
    [CX] [Option Start] Value: 8 [Option End]
```

The POSIX issues 7 and 6 specifications state that char has 8 bits.

POSIX standard before issue 6 did *not* require that. From the same site:

> CHANGE HISTORY
>
> Issue 6
>
> The values for the limits {CHAR_BIT}, {SCHAR_MAX}, and {UCHAR_MAX} are now required to be 8, +127, and 255, respectively.

---

> I don't know to what extent Linux and *BSD systems "must" conform to it

To no extent. Linux and BSD systems may not conform to any standard and may break any conformance at any time. There is no "POSIX standard police" that would enforce anything. POSIX certifications are very rare. Both systems come with a license that clearly states that there are no guaranteeing nothing. Example from BSD:

> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED `'AS IS″ AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, WITHOUT LIMITATION, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: [I wouldn't rely on Linux being beholden to following POSIX standards...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21270580/4756299)  More likely they'll whinge for two decades to get the standards lowered...

Comment: A minor nitpick.  POSIX.1 is technically a standard - not a specification.  SUS is a specification.